# Slot Machine Code Problem

Tags: java, if-statement

I've got everything finished for the program, but it's telling me that the "else if" won't work because I don't have an "if" but I have the "if" right above it. I tried making them all "if" to see if it worked but then it just makes the player win everytime without being able to exit. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RayokovichD_Homework2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Coins = 1000;
        int Wager;




        System.out.println("Slot Machine");
        System.out.println("You have " + Coins + " coins.");
        System.out.println("Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that many coins per spin.");




        while (Coins > 0)
        {




        int x = new Random().nextInt(9);
        int y = new Random().nextInt(9);
        int z = new Random().nextInt(9);

        Wager = input.nextInt();

        if(Wager > Coins)
                 Wager = Coins;

        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);


        if(x == y && x == z)
             Coins = Coins + (Wager * 100);
             System.out.println("You won " + (Wager * 100) + "!" + " You now have " + Coins + " coins.");
             System.out.println("Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that many coins per spin.");

        else if((x == y && x != z) || (x != y && x == z) || (x != y && y == z))
             Coins = Coins + (Wager * 10);
             System.out.println("You won " + (Wager * 10) + "!" + " You now have " + Coins + " coins.");
             System.out.println("Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that many coins per spin.");

        else ((x != y && x != z) || (x != y && y != z))
                 Coins = Coins - Wager;               



        }

        while (Wager == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You ran out of coins. Thanks for playing."); 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you've worked with python right?;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the braces! use:

```
if( boolean equation ) {
    many_statements;
    many_statements;
    many_statements;
}
```

OR

```
if( boolean equation ) 
    on_single_statement;
```

Comment: +1 This is why new programmers should ALWAYS use braces, even on single statements ifs.

Comment: But he already did the exact error that makes the second solution "evil" :-) :-)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I forgot about the braces around multiple statements. Thank you. And now I can't get the other "while" statement to work for pressing '0' to stop the betting. Any ideas why it won't work?

Comment: thanks byron, its better with multiple multiple statements like this :)

Comment: A couple of errors: 1) I think you mean to say "while(coin==0)" 2) you don't want to use a while loop there.. that will lead to an infinite loop.  Think through exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

you must put curly braces in every if conditions.
not because it's only 1 line of statement you didn't have to use curly braces.
Curly braces is essential you must put it.